# webdriverJS, jasmine - why isn't this test redirecting browser to specified URL?

Tags: node.js, selenium, jasmine

I am running this test suite on

- nodejs
- selenium-webdriver
- jasmine-node (using jasmine 1.3)

When I run the spec below, a browser window loads, but it doesn't redirect to the specified URL - it does nothing until test times out.

```
// testSpec.js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
    build();

jasmine.getEnv().defaultTimeoutInterval = 10000; 


describe('basic test', function () {
    it('should be on correct page', function (done) {
        driver.get('http://www.google.com');
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
            expect(title).toBe('Google');
            done();
        });

    });
});
```

how can I get the browser to redirect to the intended URL?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();
```

Refer to this article for help: http://www.techinsight.io/review/devops-and-automation/browser-automation-using-selenium-webdriver-and-nodejs/

Comment: Here is something I found: http://www.techinsight.io/review/devops-and-automation/browser-automation-using-selenium-webdriver-and-nodejs/

Comment: ah thanks, it seems the answer is there. The linked page implies that Jasmine 1.3 doesnt support the `done` parameter, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome browser in NodeJs, you can use:-

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder();
driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```